# When I open Brave browser in 20.10 and scroll within the pages there is some type of wave coming on the screen

Tags: gnome, upgrade, freeze, 20.10, brave

I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 20.10. When I open Brave browser in 20.10 and scroll within the pages there is some type of wave coming on the screen. I tried other web browsers, but the problem is same.

1. The browser is taking too much time and also when I scroll there is a wave coming in between the screen.
2. I have enabled auto-hiding the  taskbar, but it's not working. Also the taskbar is flickering when I open the web browser and it's full screen.

Brave browser - Version 1.24.71
Chromium: 90.0.4430.72 (official uild) beta (64-bit)
Ubuntu 20.10 64-bit
GNOME 3.38.3
CPU: Intel Core i3-3110M @ 2.40 GHz x 4

When writing this question the Settings window froze. I installed other web browsers, but the problem remains the same.

Comment: The current latest/stable version of Brave Browser is version 1.23.73 from the ubuntu software center. You should report a broken site through the Brave Browser using the hamburger menu option.

Comment: its happening in each and every website and i checked the beta & stable version . the problem persist .

Comment: There appears to be an issue with Brave in v20.10 in that it won't install cleanly (on my 20.10 development system) so report it as a bug to them [here](https://support.brave.com/hc/en-us)

Comment: i had reported  that...should i install the ubuntu 21.04? is it good time to do this upgrade

Comment: entirely up to you about 21.04 but look through some of this issues being reported on AU and decide if/how they might impact on you if ubuntu is mission critical - only you can answer that question. 20.04 is the current LTS version with support for some time to come.

Comment: OKAY..Then it will be worth to wait..